# Analyzing the probability distribution of nodes in a network through networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am using python's networkx to analyze the attributes of a network, I want to draw a graph of power law distribution.This is my code.

```
degree_sequence=sorted(nx.degree(G).values(),reverse=True) 
plt.loglog(degree_sequence,marker='b*')
plt.show()
```

This is my graph:[image]

But this is not a graph about the probability distribution of nodes'degree, it is the distribution of node's degree.How to convert draw a graph about the probability distribution of nodes'degree

Comment: For what it's worth, for degree distributions it's often better to plot the "complementary cumulative probability distribution", that is `1-P(k>x)` rather than plotting `P(k=x)`

Comment: How to plot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to construct a histogram of the degrees, i.e. hist[x] = number of nodes with degree x, and then normalize hist to sum up to one.

Alternatively flip your axes and normalize such that the values sum to one.

Comment: Thanks you very much!